# How to get exactly url from document.referrer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, referrer

I am using React and I am getting the document referrer using

> document.referrer

However when I am directed to my url from google.com, I am just getting the domain in document.referrer instead of something like this: `https://www.google.com/search?q=fb&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN850IN850&oq=fb&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j46i199i291i433j0i131i433l2j0i395j69i60l3.1007j1j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8`.

Is there someway I can get the entire URL including pathname and query string? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Websites can set a [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy). If they don't then, as of version 85, Chrome defaults to `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`. (Other browsers will have their own defaults, but Chrome's marketshare makes it worth highlighting)

This means that the referrer information will include only the *origin* and not the full URL.

This is a feature designed to protect the user's privacy.

There is no way around it unless you control the site that controls the *link* (in your example: `www.google.com`).

Comment: So that means the browser controls it? Or does the linking website (google.com in this case) controls it?

Comment: Ultimately the browser controls it. Most browsers will obey the `Referrer-Policy` header that the previous site used to tell the browser what to put in the referrer for subsequent requests.